# MEX function crashes when input variable size excceds limit

Tags: matlab, mex, 32-bit

I wrote my bottleneck function into a parallelized MEX function with MATLAB coder and it works fine so far.

But at certain points the function crashes with an `Unexpected unknown exception from MEX file.`
I marked some points in the function that they will display letters like 'a' so that a see where in the MEX function the error happens since I can't put breakpoint inside anymore. It didn't even come to the first letter, so the error must happen while initializing the function.

I recognized that the error always happens when the input variable size exceeds a certain limit.
The main input variables alongside some double 1x1 values are 3 nx1 double arrays and one nxn logical matrix. n can vary in size and will change size during the iterations, so I declared the as `:Inf:1` and `:Inf:Inf:` in coder.

The problem appears when n exceeds a value of about 45000. I don't know the exact value since in one iterations when its below the value everything is fine and in the next one when its above that one it crashes.

When analysing it further I saw that it seems to happen when the nxn matrix exceeds a size of 2^31 bytes.

When I want to translate my code into MEX with the matrix that doesn't load into the MEX function I get an error with something like "error with intmax()... not supported"

So I guess that coder writes MEX functions for 32-bit systems and when loading a matrix larger than that there is no pointer to point to the right element in the matrix due to the 32 bit system?

How do I bypass that problem?
Since the matrix is a boolean matrix I now found out that MATLAB supports sparse matrices and that this would save a lot of memory since only 1/10^4 of my elements are 1, but I still would like to know if the problem above results from the 32bit MEX functions and if so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this issue is caused by the MEX-file being limited to 32-bit indexing. This is a limit in Coder:

> For variable-size arrays that use dynamic memory allocation, the maximum number of elements is the smaller of:
>
> - `intmax('int32')`.
> - The largest power of 2 that fits in the C int data type on the target hardware.
>
> These restrictions apply even on a 64-bit platform.

See [this documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/array-size-restrictions-for-code-generation.html)

---

As far as I can tell, the only workaround is to have Coder generate C or C++ code for you, and you manually editing the code to use `size_t` instead of `int` for indexing (and of course remove any checks for array size). I have never worked with code generated by Coder, so am not sure how hard this is. I have written many MEX-files in C and C++ though, and these MEX-files work perfectly fine with 64-bit indexing and larger than 2 Gb arrays.

Comment: since I use coder because I am not comfortable with c++:       


{
  int32_T loop_ub;
  int32_T end;
  real_T mean_D;
  int32_T i;
  coder::array<boolean_T, 1U> r;
  coder::array<real_T, 1U> b_rhos;
  coder::array<real_T, 1U> b_dias;
  coder::array<int32_T, 1U> r1;
  int32_T b_i;           

here I should change the int32_T by size_t?

Comment: @Marc: Yes, but you also have to adjust where the input MATLAB array is accepted. I don't know where this happens. Likely in the constructor to `coder::array<T, 1U>`. You'd have to replace those by standard C MEX API functions. This is probably not going to be trivial. If you're not comfortable with C++, this is likely out of your reach. Sorry.